# [Q]How to catch Error 404: SRVE0190E

Tags: java, struts, websphere

I'm trying to capture the 404 error using a filter defined in the web.xml i defined my filter like this

```
public class StatusValidationFilter implements Filter
{

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletrequest, ServletResponse servletresponse,
            FilterChain filterchain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)servletresponse;


        if (!(response instanceof StatusExposingServletResponse)) 
        {
            response = new StatusExposingServletResponse(response);
        }

        filterchain.doFilter(servletrequest, response); 

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I defined my wrapper like this:

```
public class StatusExposingServletResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper 
{

    public StatusExposingServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }


    public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {

        if(sc == HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        super.sendError(sc);
    }

    public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException {
        super.sendRedirect(location);
    }


}
```

Ok, then in the web.xml defined the filter and the mappings like this:

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>StatusValidationFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.test.StatusValidationFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>StatusValidationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But is not catching the 404 error, is just calling the filter when the url maps to the url mapped by the ActionServlet, it means, finish with .do
I tried changing the property in the WAS com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility=true but still not working and i don't have any else idea of how to fix it, any help will ve appreciated.

Comment: See [Best way to handle 404 - page not found error in a jsp.](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=29287#165503)

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but is not working, i added the error pages and nothing..., i think the issue is some with WAS, because in debug any filter is called... i don't really know why

Comment: So, the problem is that when the WAS throw a 404 error when i try to access to a page that doesn't exists the filters aren't called... but when the URL finishes with .do, the filters are called..., anyone knows why is having this behaivour???

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokefilterscompatibility=true
```

in Servers -> Server -> Web Container Settings -> Web Container -> Custom Properties.

See more at: http://frightanic.com/software-development/solution-to-error-404-srve0190e-on-websphere-6-1